# Will i be able to use samba share and access file from ubuntu on windows if ping shows destination unreachable

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, ping, samba

I have an ubuntu machine .Its ip is 192.168.1.70 ..

I have another machine its ip is 192.168.1.45

When i ping from windows to ubuntu machine or ubuntu to windows machine by connecting to earth 4222 ont (router)  i get destination unreachable

```
From 192.168.1.70 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.70 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

When i asked the internet service provider helpline they are telling me to set up samba and start sharing ..you dont need to able to ping ...is it true

I am very much new to networking field ..so please help me

Result of arp -a

```
EARTH-4222.bbrouter (192.168.1.1) at bc:62:d2:1d:e9:e0 [ether] on enp2s0
EARTH-4222.bbrouter (192.168.1.1) at bc:62:d2:1d:e9:e0 [ether] on wlp1s0
? (192.168.1.49) at f8:b4:6a:b1:46:4a [ether] on wlp1s0
? (192.168.1.45) at <incomplete> on enp2s0
```

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Does each machine have the others IP address in its arp cache after attempting to ping?

Comment: @davidgo i dont know to check that ...I have posted the arp -a result here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Samba is over TCP and ping is over ICMP, these are two quite different network protocols. So, it is technically possible that some network device is configured to block ICMP traffic, while still allowing TCP traffic, although in my experience this type of configuration is rare on consumer devices. In that case, ping would fail while Samba may still work, but I would say this is an uncommon situation. Where I would say it is the most common for that to happen is if you are on a VPN.

Comment: ...thanks a lot ..for the beautiful explanation

Comment: While true, this doesn't have anything to do with OP's problem, as their post shows ARP queries being lost – the OS can't even start *sending* ICMP (or TCP) traffic in this situation; Samba can't work without ARP any more than ping can.

Comment: @user1686 fair enough, although that information was not part of the question at the time I answered.

Answer (score 1):

You have a network problem you need to solve before SAMBA will work.

As it stands your computers need to be able to communicate directly with esch other but are unable to.  We know this because the arp entry for 192.168.1.45 sjows up and is incomplete.

Are you sure your machine has an ip of 192.168.1.45 and not 192.168.1.49?  If so, can 192.168.1.45 ping the router or get online?  I suspect that Linux is not recognising its network card.